# Devexpress WPF - TileLayoutControl group margin

Tags: wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm trying to set a margin between 2 groups in Devexpress `TileLayoutControl`.

I'm creating 2 tiles like this:

```
        <LayoutControl:Tile Background="Green"
                            Header="User Management"
                            Size="Large" 
                            LayoutControl:FlowLayoutControl.IsFlowBreak="True" />

        <LayoutControl:Tile Background="Green"
                            Header="User Management"
                            Size="ExtraSmall" />
```

And it shows in different 'Groups' but the margin between that is pretty big. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

To set margin of Tilelayoutcontrol simply set the **TileLayoutControl.Padding** property

Comment: This will just change padding for whole control. I'm asking about margin/padding of a TileGroup.